# Determine if the following short exact sequence is split.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

Do the following short exact sequences split?

$$0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2 \longrightarrow 0$$

$$0\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow 0$$

This is a question on a Ph.D Topology exam.  I know what it means to be a split short exact sequence.  In order for the short exact sequence $0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 0$ split you need one of the following:

1. there exists map $B\longrightarrow A$ such that $A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow A$ is the identity on $A$.
2. there exists map $C\longrightarrow B$ such that $C\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C$ is the identity on $C$.
3. $B$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $A$ and $C$.

I have tried to find examples and nonexamples online of split short exact sequences and I've tried to figure out how to answer the above question, but I am struggling hard.  I've tried to use the fact that these sequences are exact so we have the fact that the $Im(f_i)=Ker(f_{i+1})$. If someone could please give me an explanation to this question I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? Any abelian groups?

Comment: $\mathbb Z^2$ is projective, so every short exact sequence ending with it splits.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: We aren't given any information about $A$ and $B$.

Comment: How do you know $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is projective?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer. Let me know if there is anything else I can help.

Answer (score 5):

I assume the sequences are of abelian groups. The first one splits since the right term is a free abelian group. The second one does not necessarily split, since one can take $A=\mathbb Q$ and $B$ the quotient. Since the middle term is torsion free, the sequence cannot split.

Comment: This "already" works with $A=\frac12\Bbb Z$

Comment: Okay, work with me here I'm still not good with this splitting business.  So, for the sequence $0\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q/Z}\longrightarrow 0 $, we would need $\mathbb{Q/Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q/Z}$ to be the identity of $\mathbb{Q/Z}$, correct? So with the rationals being torsion free and the quotient being torsion, then the conclusion breaks, correct? could you explain a little more for me.

Comment: @Michael You cannot have $\mathbb Q\simeq \Bbb Z\oplus T$ with $T$ torsion, because $\mathbb Q$ has no torsion.

Comment: The fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is torsion free also implies that any group homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ must be trivial. Every element of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ has finite order, and so must be sent to an element of finite order in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 5):

For the first short exact sequence, note that $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it is thus projective and the short exact sequence thus splits. In fact, a characterizing property for projective modules is the following.

**$M$ is a projective $R$-module if and only if any short exact sequence 
$$0\longrightarrow K\longrightarrow L\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow 0$$of $R$-modules splits.**

The above proposition already implies the second short exact sequence does not necessarily split. An explicit example can be the following

$$0\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow 0,$$ where the first map is the multiply by $2$ map while the second may is the natural projection(or modulo $2$ map). Note this short exact sequence does not split since $\mathbb{Z}$ is torsion free.

Hope the above helps.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the groups involved here are commutative. The first sequence splits because $Z^2$ is a free abelian group. if $f:B\rightarrow Z^2$, $f(u)=e_1,f(v)=e_2,$ where $e_1,e_2$ are generators of $Z^2$, write $g(e_1)=u, g(e_2)=v$.

Comment: You can just force $g(e_1)=u$ and $g(e_2)=v$? Also, do you have that $f(u)=e_1$ and $f(v)=e_2$ since $f$ is onto? So everything in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ gets mapped to?

Comment: yes, you can just force $g(e_1)=u, g(e_2)=v$ since $Z^2$ is the free abelian group. A morphism $g:Z^2\rightarrow B$ where $B$ is abelian is determined by $g(e_1)$ and $g(e_2)$, for $x\in Z^2$, you can write $x=ae_1+be_2, a,b\in Z$, then write $g(x)=au+bv$. There exists $u,v\in B$ with $f(u)=e_1, f(v)=e_2$ since $f$ is onto.